# Redirect If On Iphone/Ipod What about Ipad/Ipad Mini

Tags: html, ios, iphone, css, ipad

My question today is how may I redirect a Ipad user to a different website. For Iphone/Ipod It was simple:

```
    <script language=javascript>
    <!--
        if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
        location.replace("#");
        }
    -->
</script>
```

What I want to do be able to do the same but on Ipad/Ipad Mini. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about iPad mini but for iPad you can use this

```
navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
```

you can also write a rule in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*iPad.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com [R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Solved the problem I was having!